# Detect when Binary Formatter finishes serializing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization, wait, binaryformatter

I have a "Save And Quit" Button in my Game. I Made it and it saves the game as intended. Everything works fine, HOWEVER if i then want to close the game, I need to know when the serialization finished because if i close the game to early its not saved :(.
I await some good answers :). Thanks in advance, Here's the code (that works!):

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/Gmaster.fun";

FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

PlayerData data = new PlayerData();

Formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
stream.Close();
```

Comment: According to [Deserialization risks in use of BinaryFormatter and related types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide), _The BinaryFormatter type is dangerous and is not recommended for data processing. Applications should stop using BinaryFormatter as soon as possible, even if they believe the data they're processing to be trustworthy. BinaryFormatter is insecure and can't be made secure._

Comment: The following may be helpful: [FileStream.Dispose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.dispose?view=netframework-4.8) and [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)

Comment: I appreciate your help but those websites are written in very difficult language and from what i could understand dont really seem to fix the issue. Thanks anyway

Comment: As per my previous comment _The BinaryFormatter type is dangerous and is not recommended for data processing_. You'll need to perform some more research and try a different approach.

Comment: Use a semiphore like waittone which will lock code to prevent closing.  Add the waitone before and after the serialize that will stop code from exiting until the serialize is complete : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.autoresetevent?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0):

Create an Event and invoke it from the class:

```
public event System.Action OnSerializeDone;
```

somewhere else:

```
thatClass.OnSerializeDone += MyClass_SerializeDone;
```

at the end of your code:

```
OnSerializeDone?.Invoke();
```